# How to re-order Firestore 'modified' changes using DocumentChange.newIndex?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the web API for Firestore to perform a simple query ordered on a date property formatted as a string ('2017-12-30'). I use the onSnapshot() method to subscribe as a listener to document changes. The initial population of list of results works as expected - the order is correct.

As I make changes to the data, the callback then gets called with a change type of 'modified'. If any of the changes affects the date property, then I have no way of re-ordering the item in the list of results - unlike the old Realtime Database. That is, until I saw the newIndex and oldIndex properties of DocumentChange. They are undocumented for the Web API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange), but are documented as part of the Node.js API (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/DocumentChange).

So, my problem seemed to be solved - except that in practice the values in newIndex and oldIndex seem to be largely random and bear no relation to the actual order if I refresh the query. I can't make out any pattern that would explain the index values I get back.

Has anyone used DocumentChange.newIndex and DocumentChange.oldIndex successfully? If not, how would you reorder results in subscribers as a result of changes?

```
const query = firestore.collection(`users/${uid}/things`).
  orderBy('sortDate', 'desc').limit(1000)
query.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges.forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      dispatch(addThing({
        id: change.doc.id, 
        ...change.doc.data()
      }, change.newIndex)
    }
    if (change.type === "modified") {
      dispatch(changeThing({
        id: change.doc.id, 
        ...change.doc.data()
      }, change.oldIndex, change.newIndex))
    }
    if (change.type === "removed") {
      dispatch(removeThing(change.doc.id, change.oldIndex))
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I use the indexes for keeping a local array in sync with the data on the server and have had no issues. It's hard to see what "random" means here though. Can you show some sample data, a change that you make to that data, and the events (including indexes) that you get for that change?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I've spent some time working on a test case, which worked perfectly. I then determined that in my original code (a) there was a bug in my add logic that reversed the order elements were added; which masked an error (b) that my sort order was in the wrong direction. Effectively this meant that the indexes coming in were for the opposite sort order of the query. This muddled code is half-way migrated from the Realtime DB to Firestore. Anyway, thanks for your offer of help. I'll post the test case as the answer in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Great to hear that you found the problem Alex. And thanks for sharing it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem I had with the DocumentChange indexes was due to a couple of bugs elsewhere in my code. As I didn't find any examples of this in use outside of the Node.js Firestore docs, here's the test code I used to verify its correct behaviour (ES6). It assumes `firebase` has been initialized.

```
cleanTestData = (firestore, path) => {
  console.log("Cleaning-up old test data")
  var query = firestore.collection(path)
  return query.get().then(snapshot => {

    const deletePromises = []
    if (snapshot.size > 0) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        deletePromises.push(doc.ref.delete().then(() => {
          console.log("Deleted ", doc.id)
        }))
      });
    }
    return Promise.all(deletePromises)
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Old test data cleaned-up")
  })
}

createTestData = (firestore, path) => {
  console.log("Creating test data")
  const batch = firestore.batch()    
  const data = { 
    a: '2017-09-02',
    b: '2017-12-25',
    c: '2017-10-06',
    d: '2017-08-02',
    e: '2017-09-20',
    f: '2017-11-17' 
  }
  for (const id in data) {
    batch.set(firestore.collection(path).doc(id), { date: data[id] })
  }

  return batch.commit().then(() => {
    console.log("Test data created");
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error("Failed to create test data: ", error);
  })
}

subscribe = (firestore, path) => {
  const datesArray = []

  return firestore.collection(path).orderBy('date', 'asc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {  
    snapshot.docChanges.forEach(change => {
      console.log(change.type, "id:", change.doc.id, 
        "; date:", change.doc.data().date, 
        "; oldIndex:", change.oldIndex, "; newIndex:", change.newIndex,
        "; metadata: ", change.doc.metadata)
      if (change.oldIndex !== -1) {
        datesArray.splice(change.oldIndex, 1);
      }
      if (change.newIndex !== -1) {
        datesArray.splice(change.newIndex, 0, change.doc.data().date);
      }
      console.log("    -->", JSON.stringify(datesArray))
    })
  })
}

update = (firestore, path) => {
  console.log("Updating test data")
  return firestore.collection(path).doc('d').set({date: '2018-01-02'}).then(() => {
    console.log("Test doc 'd' updated from '2017-08-02' to '2018-01-02'")
  })
}

query = (firestore, path) => {
  var query = firestore.collection(path).orderBy('date', 'asc')
  return query.get().then(snapshot => {

    const dates = []
    if (snapshot.size > 0) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        dates.push(doc.data().date)
      });
    }

    console.log("Fresh query of data: \n    -->", JSON.stringify(dates))
  })
}

handleStartTest = e => {
  console.log("Starting test")

  const firestore = firebase.firestore()
  const path = `things`
  let unsubscribeFn = null

  unsubscribeFn = this.subscribe(firestore, path)
  this.cleanTestData(firestore, path).then(() => {
    return this.createTestData(firestore, path)
  }).then(() => {
    return this.update(firestore, path)
  }).then(() => {
    return this.query(firestore, path)
  }).then(() => {
    unsubscribeFn()
    console.log("Test complete")
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Test failed: ", error)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it worked for me:

```
onSnapshot((ref) => {
  ref.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    const { newIndex, oldIndex, doc, type } = change;
    if (type === 'added') {
      this.todos.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data());
      // if we want to handle references we would do it here
    } else if (type === 'modified') {
      // remove the old one first
      this.todos.splice(oldIndex, 1);
      // if we want to handle references we would have to unsubscribe
      // from old references' listeners and subscribe to the new ones
      this.todos.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data());
    } else if (type === 'removed') {
      this.todos.splice(oldIndex, 1);
      // if we want to handle references we need to unsubscribe
      // from old references
    }
  });
});
```

[source](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/#why)